# setState() function doesn't work and I cannot update my states. How can I solve this problem?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, setstate

I want to update my states for controlling my Models, but it doesn't work when I run this code.

These are my states which are controlling the model's visibility

```
state = {
    loginWithMail: false,
    registerWithMail:true,
    remember:true,
  }
```

That's what I tried in function.

```
    this.setState({
        registerWithMail: false,
        loginWithMail: true,
      })
      console.log(this.state)
  };
```

And this is my model which is I tried to control

```
 <Modal isVisible={this.state.registerWithMail}>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`setState` is async, so you would need to put the console.log into the callback provided by `setState` to log once the state is updated.

```
    this.setState({
        registerWithMail: false,
        loginWithMail: true,
      }, () => console.log(this.state))
  };
```

Also I believe react native modal needs this property unless that is a custom component you created `<Modal visible={this.state.registerWithMail}>`

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/modal.html#visible

Comment: It's not about console.log, I want to change the visibility of the models with setState